# Is the commutator subgroup functor exact?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm wondering whether the commutator subgroup functor on the category of groups is an exact functor in the sense that it preserves exact sequences of the form $A \rightrightarrows B \to C$ where the pair of left arrows form the kernel pair of the right arrow, and the right arrow is the coequalizer of the pair of left arrows.

In addition, I would be like to know what limits/colimits it preserves in general.

Answer (score 1):

I think none of the coequilizer $C_2\times C_2 \rightrightarrows\mathfrak S_4$ (embedding and zero morphism), coproduct $C_2\rightarrow C_2*C_2\leftarrow C_2$ or equilizer $\mathfrak S_4\rightrightarrows\mathfrak S_3$ (quotient and zero morphism) is preserved. But I think finite product is preserved in the commutator subgroup functor.